# Завершение скрипта

Tags: python

Пока что сделал простенькую штучку, и уже есть проблема. После прописывания "команды", скрипт завершается, хотелось бы узнать, как это исправить.
Сам код:

```
text = input("Введите комманду:")

#помощь
if text == "help":
    print("Все ваши команды распущены по модулям. Чтобы узнать команды определённого модуля "
                     "пропишите следующие:\n/Vk - Открывает модуль с вконтактом.\n/yout - открывает модуль с "
                     "ютубом\n/dnev - открывает дневник\n/fan - открывает веселье\n/open - открывает сайты")

#открытие
elif text == "open":
    print("opvk -открывает вк\nopd -открывает donation alerts\nopy -открывает ютуб\n"
                                          "oph -открывает сайт с помощью\nopk -открывает заметки\n")
```

p.s Команд нету, просто нужно знать способ решения

Comment: Зациклить весь ваш код или в конце кода пишите `input()`, чтобы программа не завершалась пока юзер что-нибудь не введет

Comment: а почему он не должен завершаться? он делает именно то, что вы напрограммировали.

Comment: @gil9red Можно подробнее про зацикливание кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать цикл `while`, если я Вас правильно понял. При вводе `stop` цикл завершится и программа закроется.

```py
text = ''
while text != "stop":
    text = input("Введите команду:")

    #помощь
    if text == "help":
        print("Все ваши команды распущены по модулям. Чтобы узнать команды определённого модуля "
                         "пропишите следующие:\n/Vk - Открывает модуль с вконтактом.\n/yout - открывает модуль с "
                         "ютубом\n/dnev - открывает дневник\n/fan - открывает веселье\n/open - открывает сайты")

    #открытие
    elif text == "open":
        print("opvk -открывает вк\nopd -открывает donation alerts\nopy -открывает ютуб\n"
                                              "oph -открывает сайт с помощью\nopk -открывает заметки\n")
```

Comment: ```Введите команду:help
Введите команду:stop

Process finished with exit code 0``` - Работает только стоп, остальное не работает

Comment: полностью код скопируйте, все работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще один `input()` добавить

```
text = input("Введите комманду:")

#помощь
if text == "help":
    print("Все ваши команды распущены по модулям. Чтобы узнать команды определённого модуля "
                     "пропишите следующие:\n/Vk - Открывает модуль с вконтактом.\n/yout - открывает модуль с "
                     "ютубом\n/dnev - открывает дневник\n/fan - открывает веселье\n/open - открывает сайты")
#открытие
elif text == "open":
    print("opvk -открывает вк\nopd -открывает donation alerts\nopy -открывает ютуб\n"
                                          "oph -открывает сайт с помощью\nopk -открывает заметки\n")

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: Не решение проблемы, но было полезно

Comment: Ок. Я так понял Ваш вопрос) Еще я бы посоветовал Вам вместо if завести словарь с ключами в виде запросов и значениями в виде команды или вывода текста. Будет удобнее работать с ними.